# Is there any way I can write a GraphQL query to fetch Shopify product reviews

Tags: graphql, shopify, gatsby

I am using Shopify as backend and GatsbyJs as frontend to create an e-commerce website. I am using GraphQL to query products, variants and blogs which is working fine. Now I want to show product reviews on my frontend and let customers write reviews too. For this I have used Product Review app in Shopify and now I am able to view/write reviews in Shopify, but I want to do this through Gatsby (my frontend), which I am unable to do as I cant find the approriate query in GraphQL. Is there any way I can do it or do I need something other than GraphQL.

Comment: Can you give more details by showing us the essential parts of your code?

Comment: use Shopify GraphiQL to browse available types and (for updates) mutations - if supported at all - product review is a **plugin**, configuration can be required, can be unsupported on APIs, too

Comment: Product reviews saves the information via a metafield. If you query the product metafields you will have access to the reviews.

Comment: share the URL of your shop

Comment: @xadm, GraphiQL doesnt show any query for product review. I am trying mutation but no success yet.

Comment: product query (returned type) has metafield ?